# Isolating the top-level domain of URL

Tags: python, string, url, url-parsing

I need a string method to isolate the top-level domain of a URL in Python. For example, consider the URL

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
```

I want to extract just the `".com"` without anything after or before that.

I tried something naiive:

```
domain = URL.split(".")
```

Comment: You probably need some list of all available domains. Consider that some top-level domains have two components, e.g. (`.co.uk`, `.gov.uk` etc.)

Answer (score -2):

Use the standard library's URL parser ([`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)) to extract the host name, then split on `.` to retrieve the TLD:

```
import urllib.parse

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
hostname = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).hostname
*_, tld = hostname.split(".")

>>> print(hostname)
'stackoverflow.com'
>>> print(tld)
'com'
```

Comment: Isn't there a way just using string manipulation?

Comment: This is incorrect for TLDs which do not permit registration at the top level.